# Как обеспечить сжатие PDF файла средствами JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Делаю проект на React. Помогите сделать компресию pdf файла.
Генерирую pdf с помощью пакета jspdf. В нем я включаю компресию но файл остается достаточно большим. Файл с картинками. Средний размер pdf под 20мб. Нужно максимальное сжатие. Задача иметь файл 3-4мб

```
let pdf = new jsPDF({
  orientation: 'portrait',
  unit: 'pt',
  format: [612, 792],
  putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
  compress: true // эта часть почемуто не делает разницу
});
```

Картинки вставляю так

```
pdf.addImage(
  logo,
  'JPEG',
  marginLeftFirstCol,
  marginTopFirstCol,
  150,
  logo.height / (logo.width / 150),
  null,
  'MEDIUM',
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pdf.addImage(
  logo,
  'JPEG',
  marginLeftFirstCol,
  marginTopFirstCol,
  150,
  logo.height / (logo.width / 150),
  undefined,
  'FAST',
);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]